# Why form submits when using history goback

Tags: reactjs

As the title suggests, it's a question.

```js
//FaqUpdateContainer.js
 const goToback = () => {
    history.goBack();
  };

  const handleUpdate = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log("whyyyyyyyyyyyy?");
  };
  return (
    <form onSubmit={handleUpdate}>
      <Containers.SideNavContainer type="sideMenu2" />
    </form>
  );
```

```js
//toolbar.js
export function UpdateToobar(props) {
  const {
    selects = [],
    title = "",
    goToback = () => {},
  } = props;
  return (
    <div className="tool">
      <div>
        <Default onClick={goToback}>
          <button>
            <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faArrowAltCircleLeft} />
          </button>
        </Default>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

When i run the history goback above☝,
the onSubmit event of the form is automatically executed.
Does anyone know why this is the case?

Comment: How is `goToback()` called? (If it's a button inside the form, that button may be defaulting to a "submit" type button)

Comment: yes.. I am using the default button.! So what should I do? please....
let me know

Answer (score 1):

You should probably assign attribute `type="button"` to go back button. Buttons have `type="submit"` by default. Please share more code to be sure

Comment: yes.. I am using the default button.!
So what should I do?

Comment: add type="button" to it